# Does Flutter Text support wrapping of long word?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to break long words into multiple lines in Flutter, like we could do with { word-wrap: break-word; } in the web?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you ask for is what this feature request is about
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18443

> Currently we do not support hyphenation in Flutter text, but there are indeed hyphenation systems in minikin that we depend on. They are currently not wired up/integrated, but I believe hyphenation is something we would want to eventually support.

Please upvote the initial comment of the issue to increase priority.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the prompt answer. Keep up the good work, flutter team! The future depends on you guys ;)

Comment: I'm not from the Flutter team. Just an enthusiastic user/developer. Thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use this String extension when you use Text Widget

```
extension WordBreakUtil on String {
  String get breakWord {
    String breakWord = '';
    runes.forEach((element) {
      breakWord += String.fromCharCode(element);
      breakWord += '\u200B';
    });
    return breakWord;
  }
}
```